# Invalid shipping address #10736 error with PayPal express checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, shipping, paypal-express

I am getting the following error every time I try to use paypal express checkout from my site though my shipping address is valid.

`PayPal NVP gateway errors: A match of the Shipping Address City, State, and Postal Code failed (#10736: Shipping Address Invalid City State Postal Code).`

I have searched a lot about this, but couldn't get the right solution. Please guide me at this point. Advice from any one will highly appreciate.

Comment: Did you found solution ?

Answer (score 4):

> Its Work for me!! please open this file.

/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php file**

```
$request['ADDROVERRIDE'] = 1;
```

to

```
$request['ADDROVERRIDE'] = 0;
```

after that your customer use the Paypal checkout with not matching of state , city and postal code it’s working fine.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because paypal validates the address. As far as I can see there is no option to turn this off from the paypal side, but you could extend magento so that it sends the request to paypal without the validate address flag.

To do this what you will need to do is remove the sending of the flag `ADDROVERRIDE` in `callSetExpressCheckout`

Answer (score 1):

At the time of Paypal Express Checkout the customer enter City, State, and Postal Code if these three are not match the Paypal throws an error.

i.e,
PayPal gateway has rejected request. A match of the Shipping Address City, State, and Postal Code failed (#10736: Shipping Address Invalid City State Postal Code)
But Some of the Clients don’t want this validation.

For that you do changes on you Paypal module Api.

The change is
`/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php` file

in `callSetExpressCheckout()` Method

remove the line `$request[\’ADDROVERRIDE\’] = 1;`

after that your customer use the Paypal checkout with not matching of state , city and postal code it’s working fine.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i change in below file and its worked

```
includes/src/IWD_Opc_Model_Api_Nvp.php
```

line number 34 i change ADDROVERRIDE from 1 to 0

Comment: Because your compilation is enabled. After recompilation, this can't work.
You Need to edit this on mail file  app\code\community\IWD\Opc\Model\Api\Nvp.php